# Log file for batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2003-r2

I'm a beginner in scripting, I just made a batch script to create some quotas on a server Win2003. I would like to have a log file as an output , but the only command I know is >>logfile.txt which will make a log file for each command.

I would like to have ONE logfile.txt that will log if all commands were successfully applied or not...

Can someone help please with the coding please?

```
@echo off
echo.
Dirquota quota add "J:\P1\BD OG" /Limit:60GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
Dirquota quota add "J:\P1\BD Chair" /Limit:60GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
Dirquota quota add "M:\P2\BD Arena" /Limit:50GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
Dirquota quota add "K:\P3\BD Home" /Limit:30GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
echo.
pause
```

Comment: `>>logfile.txt` after each command will work. It appends to the file if it exists already. `>logfile.txt` (only one `>`) is the version that overwrites the file if it exists.

Comment: Thank you , but the thing is that I have more than 200 commands [I just put 4 on this post] , I don't want to have a log file for each command... I want to have 1 log file and within that file check if each command has been successfully applied or not....

Comment: You will have one log file if you use `>>logfile.txt`. It will not create one file per command. If you don't want the entire output of all commands in that file, then it depends how `dirquota` signals that it failed. You'll have to check that somehow, and then log the result with `echo Failed >> logfile.txt` or `echo Success >> logfile.txt`.

Comment: Great tips! You are right... I will need the entire output. Where do I put >>logfile.txt on the script ? at the end of the first command?

Comment: It will need to go at the end of every command that you want to include in the log.

Comment: Just execute the Batch file this way: `theBatchFile.bat > logfile.txt`

Comment: @Aacini: That is genious. Thanks so much was looking for this way of checking batch files for so long. Thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4" %%a IN (q24521687.txt) DO (
  ECHO(Dirquota quota add "%%a:\%%b\BD %%c" /Limit:%%dGB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO failed) ELSE (ECHO succeeded)
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

This batch routine uses a file named `q24521687.txt` containing this data (derived from yours)

```
J P1 OG 60
J P1 Chair 60
M P2 Arena 50
K P3 Home 30
```

Which may be easier to maintain.

Produces newfile.txt - this could be any filename you choose. Use `>>` in place of `>` to append to an existing file (or create it if it doesn't exist) `>` will replace any existing file.

Note that this will simply `ECHO` the `dirquota` command-line for checking (to the `newfile.txt` file). Delete the `echo(` to invoke the executable.

I've assumed that `dirquota` uses the standard `errorlevel` setting - 0 for success, non-zero otherwise. Without your specifying what the termination condition for `dirquota` is, I would be guessing.

---

Response to comments:

There's no indication about `BD` - is it part of **every** name to be constructed in that position, or only **some**?

The `for /f` parses the lines of the input file and assigns each token on the line to `%%a..%%d` (`%%a` is nominated, tokens 1-4 are selected, so each token on the input line is assigned to the next-alphabetical metavariable).

The default separators are <kbd>Space</kbd> and comma, amongst others. Consequently, `J P1 OG 60` for example would assign `J` to `%%a`, `P1` to `%%b`, `OG` to `%%c` and `60` to `%%d`. Hence, the `dirquota` line would be constructed as required, **assuming** (for lack of data otherwise) that all directorynames are of the form `BD something`.

With some small adjustments, this can be extended.

Suppose you wanted directorynames `BD OG`, `sausages` and `XY Table`.

Since the directory name may or may not contain a space, we could fix the routine by changing it a little:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4DELIMS=," %%a IN (q24521687.txt) DO (
  ECHO(Dirquota quota add "%%a:\%%b\%%c" /Limit:%%dGB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%c failed) ELSE (ECHO %%c succeeded)
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

(note the changes : remove the **BD<kbd>Space</kbd>** from the directory in the `dirquota` line and add the `delims=,` phrase into the `for /f`)

And our data in the text file becomes

```
J,P1,BD OG,60
J,P1,sausages,60
M,P2,XY Table,50
K,P3,BD Home,30
```

Simply each variable part separated by commas (the `delims=` character selected).

Note the positioning of the quotes. These are designed to ensure that separators are correctly processed.

As presented, since the `dirquota` command is simply `echo`ed, not executed, `errorlevel` will be `0` so each line will be reported as having succeeded (I've added `%%c` to the succeeded/failed report). Once you've checked that the `dirquota` command-lines being reported are correct, simply change `ECHO(Dirquota` to `Dirquota` and the `dirquota` lines will be executed; Assuming `dirquota` is an executable and it sets `errorlevel` to the standard `0=success;otherwise failure` then the `if errorlevel` line directly following the `dirquota` line should correctly display the result.

Comment: Thanks Magoo , so... my understanding is that I need to put the path of the folders on `q24521687.txt`?  Also I haven't put any `error level` setting. Could you please let me know where to put that ? 
Also , `BD` is part of the name of the folder , so 
will `\BD %%c"` be necessary ? or just `\%%c"/Limit:%%dGB` will do the trick ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As Aacini says in his comment, you can simply redirect output when you invoke your batch file. If your batch script is called "myScript.bat", then you can use `myScript >myLog.txt 2>&1`. If you want to append to an existing log file, then use `myScript >>myLog.txt 2>&1`.

The funny looking redirection at the end causes error messages on stderr to be redirected to the same location as stdin, which is the log file in this case. This is needed so that you can capture any error messages that DIRQUOTA may produce.

There is one problem with this approach - Your PAUSE output will also appear in the log file, and you will not see the prompt to press a key on the screen. You could solve this by obtaining a Windows port of the TEE utility that sends output to both the screen and a file.

Alternatively, you could modify your script as follows, and call it normally:

```
@echo off
call :main >myLog.txt 2>&1
pause
exit /b

:main
echo.
Dirquota quota add "J:\P1\BD OG" /Limit:60GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
Dirquota quota add "J:\P1\BD Chair" /Limit:60GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
Dirquota quota add "M:\P2\BD Arena" /Limit:50GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
Dirquota quota add "K:\P3\BD Home" /Limit:30GB /Type:Hard /Status:Enable /Add-Threshold:80 /Add-Notification:80,M,e-mail-warning.txt
echo.
exit /b
```